# Gnome - Something like Alt-Tab but corresponds to horizontal program list at bottom?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, debian, shortcuts

I'm on Debian/Gnome - I've always been using Alt Tab but sometimes I have 20 or so programs and I would prefer if I could jump to the program by hitting something like Alt+F1 or Ctrl+1 so if 'vim' is my first program listed at the bottom left then it jumps and opens it.

Or perhaps there are other window managers with something similar? I'm fine with there being a limit of 9 since I can't map something to two-digits obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my XP partition at the moment, so I can't look at the details myself, but I think you might find the options in the CCSM under Window Management useful (specifically the Window Picker or Grouping).

You would have to be using compiz (which I think comes with Jaunty) and install the CCSM.

CCSM installation discussion:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=711321

EDIT: Apparently "new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink" which is silly. I'll see if I can leave the other links in the comments.

Comment: The other links: 

             http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz             http://wiki.opencompositing.org/CCSM

Comment: @ThomasGHenry: Yeah, sometimes the spam prevention mechanisms do cause a great deal of inconvenience to legitimate users!